# Proof quotient spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U_1, U_2$ be a vector subspace of the vector space V and $ U_1 \subseteq U_2 $.

Show: $V/U_2 ≅ (V/U_1)/(U_2/U_1).$

Well.. Do I have to show that the left side is nearly the same as the right one?

Isn't:

$V/U_2 := \{v + U_2 : v \in V \}$

$V/U_1 := \{v + U_1 : v \in V \}$

$U_2/U_1 := \{a + U_1 : a \in U_2 \}$

so
$(V/U_1)/(U_2/U_1) := \{ \{v+U_1\} + \{a + U_1\} \} = \{ (v+a)+U_1 \}$ ?

You see, I don't get it..

Comment: Have a closer look at the quotient $(V/U_1)/(U_2/U_1)$. Do you know how it looks like (it is a bit different from what you wrote)? Do you know what an isomorphism is? Do you know the first isomorphism theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\cong$-sign wants us to find an isomorphism of the two vector spaces $V/U_2$ and  $(V/U_1)/(U_2/U_1)$. When it comes to quotient spaces it is easier to only use natural maps and to induce maps from quotients rather than giving them explicitly.

**Hint:** In your case the two inclusions $U_1 \subseteq  V$ and $U_2/U_1 \subseteq  V/U_1$  give us two natural projections $$\varphi_1 : V \rightarrow V/U_1 \\ \varphi_2 : V/U_1 \rightarrow (V/U_1)/(U_2/U_1).$$ 
Try to use them together with the 1. Isomorphism Theorem to induce the desired isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. If I have a look at f := $φ_2(φ_1)$ and if f is surjective, then: (V/U1)/(U2/U1) is isomorph to V/ker(f). So I need ker(f) which must be $U_2$ ?

Comment: Right, that's a very good idea. You have to be a bit careful when calculating the pre-image of $ker(\varphi_2)$ under $\varphi_1$. It's not super-trivial that this is indeed $U_2$.

Comment: Yes, that's my problem :) How can I calculate ker(f) ?

Comment: An element $x \in V$ satisfies $f(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \varphi_1(x) \in ker(\varphi_2)$. So it is the pre-image of $ker(\varphi_2)$  under $\varphi_1$.